# One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running. Not solved on mac

Tags: magento2, admin, cron, reindex

I have installed Magento2 on my machine, I am using osx yosemite, and on admin panel I am getting

```
One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running.
```

I have tried

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

to re index the indexes, and

```
php bin/magento cron:run
```

to run cron job, every time I am getting

```
Magento supports PHP 5.6, 7.0.2, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html
```

But I am using **php 5.6.10** on **MAMP**

Comment: try https://ranasohel.me/2016/05/29/process-indexing-from-admin-in-magento2/

Comment: @SohelRana I followed you to https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-product-indexer, here you said **copy SR folder inside app/code** in magento2, I can't find folder **Code**, should I create it

Comment: Yes, If 'code' directory is missing then create it.

Comment: getting same result 'Magento supports PHP 5.6, 7.0.2, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html'

Comment: getting above error when I try to run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** command in my magento root folder

Comment: Your CL pick wrong php version. Check your php version for CL.

Comment: **which php** shows **/usr/local/bin/php**, why is this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, I have chnaged osx'x php to MAMP's php, by following the [Instructions to Change PHP Installation](https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/5987693)
First, Lets find out what version of PHP we're running (To find out if it's the default version).

To do that, Within the terminal, Fire this command:

```
which php
```

This should output the path to the default PHP install which comes preinstalled by Mac OS X, by default it has to be (Assuming you've not changed it before):

```
/usr/bin/php
```

Now, We just need to swap this over to the PHP that is installed with MAMP, which is located at /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin (MAMP 2.1.3), or your php's version selected in MAMP

To do this, We need to edit the `.bash_profile` and add the MAMP version of PHP to the PATH variable.
Follow these simple steps:

Within the Terminal, run `vim ~/.bash_profile`

Type `i` and then paste the following at the top of the file:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:$PATH
```

Hit `ESC`, Type `:wq`, and hit `Enter`

In Terminal, run source `~/.bash_profile`

In Terminal, type in `which php` again and look for the updated string. If everything was successful, It should output the new path to MAMP PHP install.

In case it doesn't output the correct path, try closing the terminal window (exit fully) and open again, it should apply the changes (Restart in short).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try doing this:

> CD /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/bin
>   :bin > ./magento indexer:reindex
>   :bin > ./magento cron:run

Reference: https://gist.github.com/aarthiathi/2f229fa1dac007d8b43f8fc921e81218

Comment: This worked for me but my installation path was different since I didn't do the install inside MAMPs folders. Just go inside your magento2 project folder, wherever that is and navigate to the `/bin` directory. Then run the two commands above `./magento indexer:reindex` and `./magento cron:run`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In terminal, type `crontab -e`
Then enter these 2 lines:

```
*/1 * * * * php -c /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf/php.ini /path/to/your/m2installation/bin/magento cron:run
*/1 * * * * php -c /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf/php.ini /path/to/your/m2installation/bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

Save and try again.

Comment: In terminal I typed **crontab -e**, and terminal is opened in **vim** mode, I placed given two lines after editing, but unable to save it by **Esc :wq**

Comment: what message do you get when you use `:wq`? Try it from root folder of your project.

Comment: I am getting 'crontab: no crontab for AbdulGhaffar - using an empty one <br/>
crontab: "/usr/bin/vi" exited with status 1'